# How to keep video inside fragment playing after rotation?

Tags: android, video, android-fragments, android-videoview

I managed to get my video to play with VideoView but after I rotate my device video stops and starts playing from the beginning. I placed my VideoView inside fragment.

I tried this inside my fragment but without success:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(video.isPlaying()) {
        video.pause();
        progress = video.getCurrentPosition();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(video.isPlaying() && progress!=0) {
        video.seekTo(progress);
        video.start();
    }
}
```

How to keep video playing after screen rotates?

Comment: is the progress number at 0?

Comment: @tyczj, no, progress keeps track of video successfully.